# Find value of sibling element using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <p>Stories written by</p>
  <h1>Author 1</h1>
  <h5></h5>
</div>
```

I need to extract the text of `<h1>` given it is a child of div of `.container` where the first text is 'Stories written by'.

This doesn't work:

```
author_tags = $(".container")
console.log(author_tags.item(1))
```

Comment: `$('div.container h1').text()`?

Comment: Perfect!! thanks. and if i were to do using regex, in python, how would it work?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Python so cannot help with that. However parsing HTML with Regex is a really bad idea. Use a parser library.

Comment: Also note that I rolled back your edit to ask about Python as it completely changes the original question parameters. If you want to know how to achieve this in Python please start a new question.

Comment: sure yeah i understand!. will create another question

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you wish to use multiple `<div>` with that class then you can loop over those element to get the value of `<h1>`:

```js
$('div.container h1').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p>Stories written by</p>
  <h1>Author 1</h1>
  <h5></h5>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p>Stories written by</p>
  <h1>Author 2</h1>
  <h5></h5>
</div>
```